# Add Image Stored in Project Folder to Microsoft Interop Word Document

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ms-word, office-interop

I have a C# Web API and I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop to dynamically create a Word document. I have an image that I wish to add to said document. This image is stored within the project itself and not on a drive somewhere.When I add the image to the document I'm met with an error with states "This is not a valid file name". The file is definitely in the folder. Is there a special way to get C# to see the folder? I know in Javascript you would simply put ".\Images\Watermark.png". Is C# capable of handling something like that?

[image]

Comment: What value is imagePath passing to Word? Word needs a file path to a real location that it can reach...

Comment: The image is in a project folder titled Images. It's literally an image within the Images folder. Does Word have to have a full path all the way to the drive letter? If so, doesn't that mean it's impossible to use Word with a website?

Comment: Yes, Word requires a full path, including the drive letter. Some functionality can also work with a URL - not sure about this method, however. You'd need to test (as a user) - I'm on a mobile device, currently. Word is not designed to be used by a web-site, or in a server environment. It is an end-user tool. For document generation it's better to work with the Word Open XML file format, directly, using for example the Open XML SDK. The file format was designed for exactly these kinds of environments. The Word applciation does not need to be present, or licensed.

Comment: Okay, that explains why it won't work. Maybe I can find a way to just host it on the server that's going to host the website. I'll figure something out. Thank you!

Comment: You really, really, really do *NOT* want to go that route. Really.

Comment: Okay, so should I not use images with Word?

Comment: Work with the Open XML file format, not with automation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a Mail Merge document instead of trying to create the document via C#.